# Question on finding cartesian equation of a plane(general equations of a plane)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Given the equation of a plane $5x+2y-z+22=0$ ,Find the vector $\vec V$ perpendicular to the plane and point $P_o(x_o,y_o,z_o)$ on the plane ?

Trying Solutions: 
Since the general equation is  $Ax+By+Cz=D$ Where $D=Ax_o+By_o+Cz_o$
In the above $equation$, I found the $\vec V$ as $\vec V=5i+2j-k$
While $D=-22$ , hence I tried finding the point $P_o$ in the equation as $5x_o+2y_o-z_o=-22$
and am stuck at this point ? 
 Any help ?

Edit 
The teacher gave this question in reverse where we were finding the $equation$ of the cartesian plane , and the $P_o(-3,0,7)$ 
 Is it must I get these points ?

Comment: Any point on the plane will do. Try setting two of the variables to zero.

Comment: Well one valid point is $(-2,-1,0)$